# SQL Server Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL 2008 - Beginner to DBA

I am confused between SQL Server Network Configuration and Client Configuration.

Why TCP/IP is Disabled in Network ? If i enabled, whether i can access the Database from outside the network through internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Why TCP/IP is Disabled in Network ? I

After the SQL Slammer worm a lot of stuff has been disabled out of the box from SQL Server 2005 on, some other ones that are disabled are xp_cmdshell, ad-hoc queries  etc etc

You need to enable TCP/IP and make sure you are not blocking port 1433(this is the default port)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Tcp/Ip refers to whether or not the server will be accessible from remote via Tcp/Ip. You can still access the server locally if it is disabled.

Comment: Yeah, I am able to access server locally.(i.e) within my LAN. But my expectation is to access the server both locally and remotely. For instance, if i share my Server/User Credentials - You should be able to log into our Database. That's what i am expectig ..!

Comment: You can do that. Just enable remote access via Tcp/Ip. See the answer from SQLMenace - making a database server available to the public by default is not necessarily a good idea.